# How to import a mysql db into Azure sql without .net tools

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, azure

We're running Linux VM's with MySQL on Azure and want to start using Azure SQL, but need to get the data from one into the other, initially.

Is there a way to dump a mysql database and then import that into an Azure sql database?

I'm on a Mac (or can be on Linux), so the .net tools won't help.

I've tried having Azure use the mysql dump. Reads it, but nope.

I've tried selecting the mysql tables from an open connection and drop them on the Azure db, also in an open connection, via Navicat. Nope.

I also tried looking for something in SQLPro for MSSQL. Nope.

Also, I'm willing to edit the mysql dump if there are minor global things to do so that Azure sql will read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
1. Install mysql instance on windows based server.
2. Dump all your databases into there using mysql dump.
3. Use all the spectrum of microsoft tools for your goal.
```